# ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'Name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to split a column into three different columns and  insert the split values into the table.

This is the statement I am using.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (X, Y, Z)
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, "-", 1),
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, "-", -2), "-", 1),
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, "-", -1), "-", 2)
FROM table1;
```

However I get this error:

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'Name' doesn't have a default value
```

This doesn't make much sense to me because I did not call the "Name" field at all.

I know for certain that on their own the select statements work, but the insert into does not seem too.

If anyone has any advice or suggestions it would be much appreciated!

Comment: There error is *because* you didn't call the `Name` field at all. `INSERT` is for adding new rows, and you didn't provide the `Name` field for the new rows you're adding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you have a column called `name` which is declared `NOT NULL` and has no `DEFAULT` value.  `INSERT` inserts new rows and usually you want values for some or all of the columns.

I suspect that what you really want is not `INSERT`, but `UPDATE` -- to change values *within* a row:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET X = SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, '-', 1),
        Y = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, '-', -2), '-', 1),
        Z = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(XYZ, '-', -1), '-', 2);
```